# Insert multiple email to mysql using single textarea

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert multiple emails into the database using single text area.

This is my code :

*PHP*

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "emails_test";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
if (!$conn) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //$email = nl2br($_POST['email']);
    $email = explode("\r\n", $_POST['email']);

    foreach($email as $emails) {
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO emails (email) VALUES ('$emails')");
        if($query) { echo "Inserted into the database"; } else { echo"Fail, please try again"; }
    }
}
```

*HTML*

```
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="POST">
        <textarea rows="5" name="email" cols="50" ></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

I want table to be like this : [image: [Pic Table in MySQL]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `explode` to get string into array by `"\r\n"`

don't use single quotes you need to use double quotes to explode the string by `\r\n` I just got to know that.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //$email = nl2br($_POST['email']);
    $email = explode("\r\n", $_POST['email']);

    foreach($email as $emails) {
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO emails (email) VALUES ('$emails')");
        if($query) {
            echo "Inserted into the database";
        } else {
            echo "Fail, please try again";
        }
    }
}
?>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="POST">
        <textarea rows="5" name="email" cols="50" ></textarea>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Only if you are assuming he's getting a list into the text area.

Comment: yes it will works for text area, using enter key press after every email to saperate that email

Comment: Thanks. I already try to use this `$email = explode('\r\n', $_POST['email']);` but I still cant insert into database. It is anything I need to add or adjust?

Comment: it should work how you are making entries in text area can u show that entries screenshot if possible?

Comment: Why can't you try to enter email ID separated by `commas (,)` and then at PHP end use `explode(',',$_POST['email'])` then insert them..?

Comment: @Que I just updated my answer you need to use double quotes to cover `"\r\n"`

Comment: @PrateikDarji I tried both `"\r\n"` or `'\r\n'`. When I submit form, popup fail shown. No data insert to database.

Comment: @GYaN just change `explode("\r\n", $_POST['email']);` with `explode(',',$_POST['email'])` then use insert query like I post?

Comment: please make sure there is no error in database connection put this two lines just after `<?php` tag    error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', true); and then try

Comment: @Que have you checked? are you sure there is no database connection error in your code right?

Comment: @PrateikDarji Yeah i've checked. No error in database connection. I always use this `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', true);` when I start doing something.

Comment: ok so did you get fail alert of getting nothing after running this code

Comment: Yeah that's right. I follow everything but still cannot insert data to mysql

Comment: can u please update the question with your current code also mention database connection if possible

Comment: haven't you set `ini_set("display_errors",true);` just after `error_reporting` once try that and let me know if you facing any error or not

Comment: seriously, I don't understand the problem, are you getting any fail message which you have defined if query is failed? or getting nothing ?

Comment: I don't know whats the real problem sir. But I tried to delete current page and retype everything without copy paste, now it's work. omg but why. XD

Answer (score 2):

**You may try this way**

```
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="POST">
        <textarea rows="5" name="email" cols="50" ></textarea>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>


Note :- use "Enter" to put all email (one by one)
```

**Insert into database**

```
  <?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

        $str = $_POST["email"];
        $email  = preg_split('/\r\n|\n|\r/', $str);


    foreach($email as $emails) {

        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO emails (email) VALUES ('".$emails."')");

        if($query) { ?>

            <script>alert("Inserted into the database");</script>

            <?php } else { ?>

                <script>alert("Fail, please try again");</script>
    <?php } } }

    mysqli_close($conn);

    ?>
```

Example :-

[image]

Comment: Thanks Aman Kumar. Can u teach me from that array how to insert into DB?

Comment: query should not be like this it is voluntary sql injection

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your code...

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="POST">
        <textarea rows="5" name="email" cols="50" ></textarea><br>
        <small>Enter email IDs separated by comma(,)</small>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"><br>
    </form>
</body>
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email = explode(',',$_POST['email']);//convert into $email array
    $value = '';
    foreach($email as $r) $value .= '("'.$r.'"),';//concatenate email for insert
    $value = rtrim($value,',').';' //remove the last comma ;
    $query = mysqli_query('INSERT INTO emails (email) VALUES '.$value);// insert all email in database in single query in different rows
    if($query) echo 'Inserted into the database';
    else echo 'Fail, please try again";
}
```

You will get your output...

Comment: Thanks GYaN. But sorry I'm confused with this two. `foreach($email as $r) $value .= '("'.$r.'"),';` and `$value = rtrim($value,',').';'`. It is correct? Seem like something wrong.

Comment: I got the value but data still not insert into db.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work as intended if you will just replace this

```
$email = nl2br($_POST['email']);
```

with this

```
$email = preg_split('/\r\n|\n|\r/', $_POST['email']);
```

The problem is, you just have replaced all `\n\r` with `<br>\n\r`. The `nl2br` returns a string with replacements, but you need an array for using it inside the `foreach` loop.

As an additional note, you're iterating through an array and every time you are adding this instruction:

```
<script>alert("Inserted into the database");</script>
```

If you will iterate through 10 emails, you will be alerted ten times in a row.

Also, `mysql_query` is deprecated. It's time to learn either PDO, or MySQLi, which will give you ability to use placeholders instead of unsafe direct injecting `$_POST` data into SQL query. Placehiolders are pretty easy to learn, and they can help you to build more reliable applications.

Comment: Thanks @Sergey Ronin. I tried to replace `$email = preg_split('/\r\n|\n|\r/', $_POST['email']);` with my code. But still failed insert data. I also use `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);` to avoid error `mysql_query is deprecated`